# Cannot access nginx webserver behind another nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two VMs, the first one (vm-1) is running nginx as reverse proxy with the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name example.com;
  location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://ip-vm-2:8080;
  }
  location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://ip-vm-2:80;
  }
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate ....
}
```

For the second vm (vm-2), I have app1 (a standalone jar) on port 8080 which is working correctly and I can access it from https://example.com/app1.

For app2, I have installed nginx and copied a website to /var/www/html, altough I can access it from http://ip-vm-2, I does not work from https://example.com/app2, which is what I want.

I don't know exactly what the problem is with the configuration in the reverse proxy.

Comment: Doesn't the `return` statement of the first `server` block redirect to itself?

Comment: @Tommiie this statement will redirect to https any traffic coming from http

Comment: Ah, right! I didn't read the 'https' part.

Comment: Please describe `does not work` in more detail. Do you get wrong content? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error message?

Comment: I get a 404 response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried with VMs, but this seems logical.

VM1 nginx configuration

`server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name example.com;
  location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://ip-vm-2:8080;
  }
  location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://ip-vm-2;
  }
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate ....
}`

VM2 nginx configuration

`server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ip-vm-2;
  location / {
   root         /var/www/html;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ;
  }
}`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works! The only change was removing the :80 in the reverse proxy?

Comment: If you have VM2 configured to listen to `/path` over 80, then you need to access it through `/path` over http. Good!